# Unable to mutate variables in decoded instance of Codable model

Tags: ios, swift, combine

While trying to make an API call, I get a response of type `[AModelElement]`, how do I add a property of Date type that I can change values for? I am unable to add a property in the `Date` format without an initializer `Date()`, because it doesnt conform with `Decodable` protocol then, so I added another object `swiftDate` into my `AModelElement`. Builds successfully, however the values of the variables I added to the model are not getting mutated in my code. How can I achieve this?

Here's an example snippet of my model code:

```
typealias AModel = [AModelElement]
struct AModelElement: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let idEvent: Int
    let creationDate: String
    var swiftDate:Date = Date() // Added by me, removing = Date() introduces error
    var groupIndex:Int = 0 // Added by me

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case idEvent
        case creationDate = "CreationDate"
    }
}
```

Here's where I successfully make my API calls and get data:

```
let data = await makeBearerGetApiCall(endpoint: "user/events", tokenParam: token)
var decodedResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(AModel, from: data)
```

Here's how I'm trying to make changes to the variable code

```
for var event in decodedResponse{
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    event.swiftDate = dateFormatter.date(from: "2023-10-05 16:00:00") ?? Date()
    event.groupIndex = 1
}
```

The id, idEvent and creationDate values are perfectly fine, but the swiftDate shows me the current time in UTC and groupIndex is always 0 even though I am setting it otherwise. Any hints about what I am missing?

Other things I have tried:

- I tried to keep my added properties as let instead of var, but then I can't assign any values to them
- I tried to remove the default value assignment, but then I get the error that it "cannot automatically synthesize 'Decodable' because 'groupIndex' does not have a matching CodingKey and does not have a default value"

Comment: the date format "yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" should be "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" if I am correct

Comment: @aiwiguna thank you for you response! I tested it on the swift playground of my computer and it worked fine with my solution. Even if that was the problem though, it wouldn't explain why the `groupIndex` value doesn't change either

Comment: Because event is immediately going out of scope. Are you familiar with `map`? You should be using that instead your `for` loop

Comment: @Saamer I am not very familiar with for var loop that you used, maybe because of that https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/652006

Comment: @Saamer I think the issue is the for loop, because Struct is value type, it will not reference to the instance in array when you set var event in the loop, you need to change the value directly to the array like decodedResponse[0]. groupIndex = 1

Answer (score 0):

Use the `decodedResponse` array directly, such as:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

for i in decodedResponse.indices {
    decodedResponse[i].swiftDate = dateFormatter.date(from: "2023-10-05 16:00:00") ?? Date()
    decodedResponse[i].groupIndex = 1
}
print("----> decodedResponse: \(decodedResponse)")
```